# Creating a forwarded ssh connection from a middle machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I feel like I've tried every combination of the -L and -R flags with ssh and read a ton of very similar question, but can't make this work…maybe it's not possible.

There are two machines, neither of which is accessible from the outside word: `DB` & `Mid`. `DB` is a database server listening on port 1433 (and only 1433). `Mid` can connect to it on 1433. I have terminal access to `Mid`. I would like to make `DB` port 1433 available to a third computer: `Home`. I *can* ssh from `Mid` to `Home` (but not `Home` to `Mid`).

It basically looks like this:

```
DB <--[1433]--> Mid --[ssh]--> Home
```

If there some way to create a connection from `Home` to `DB` via port forwarding in such a way that traffic flows through `Mid` and allows me to access `DB` port 1433 from `Home`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work when executed on `Mid`:

```
ssh -R 1433:DB:1433 user@Home
```

This creates a tunnel from port 1433 at the Home computer to DB server port 1433.

After this, you can connect to `localhost:1433` with a program running on `Home` computer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It turns out I tried it but it didn't know it was working because I was trying to connect to localhost from docker container that wasn't wired up correctly.